# Simple if..else for command output giving wrong results

Tags: bash

I've tried many SO answers but somehow couldn't get this working.

I am writing a bash script to return a non-zero exitcode if the redis cluster is not `ok`.
This script will later be used in docker compose's `healthcheck` tag.

This is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

result="$(redis-cli -c -p 30006 --raw cluster info | grep cluster_state: | cut -d ":" -f2)"

echo "$result"

if [ "$result" = "fail" ]; then
    echo "failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

The output of the script is:

```
I have no name!@ae2197466e7b:/data$ ./redis_healthcheck.sh 
fail
I have no name!@ae2197466e7b:/data$ echo $?
0
```

When run the command from inside the container, i get:

```
I have no name!@ae2197466e7b:/data$ redis-cli -c -p 30006 --raw cluster info | grep cluster_state: | cut -d ":" -f2
fail
I have no name!@ae2197466e7b:/data$ redis-cli -c -p 30006 --raw cluster info 
cluster_state:fail
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:10923
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:5461
cluster_known_nodes:6
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:8
cluster_my_epoch:8
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:3660
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:3660
cluster_stats_messages_sent:7320
cluster_stats_messages_ping_received:3660
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:3660
cluster_stats_messages_received:7320
total_cluster_links_buffer_limit_exceeded:0
```

As seen, even though the result is `fail` the script does not enter into the `if` block.

Comment: it's possible that $result contains `"fail\r"` -- pipe the redis output through `od -c` to verify.

Comment: You're doing more work than necessary. `if redis-cli -c - p 30006 --raw cluster info | grep -q cluster_state:fail; then ...; fi`.

Comment: @glennjackman you were right! it was indeed `\r\n`.. i removed it using `tr -d '\r\n'` and it worked..

@chepner you rock! if the solution is not simple, it's probably not the best one - thanks for reminding this to me!

Comment: Have you tried capturing `stderr` as well as `stdout`?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
redis-cli -c -p 30006 --raw cluster info
```

return non-zero exit code if it fails ?

In that case

```
if $[ $( redis-cli -c -p 30006 --raw cluster info >log ) -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "failed"
    exit 1
fi
```